# how can i add a close button in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my work:

https://jsfiddle.net/anwarirumbuzhi/kt2o7443/

I want to create a CSS close button in flip area, but I don't know how to add a close script.

```
#image-expand {
    width: 116%;
    position: absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
      margin-top: 75px;
}

#image-expand div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#image-expand div .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 500;
}

#image-expand div label {
    width: 390px;
    height:80vh;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset -25px 0px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    color: #222;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#image-expand div label span {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 70px;
      font-family: 'Conv_AvenirLTStd-Medium',Sans-Serif;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      color:#373837;
      font-weight: bold;

}

#image-expand input[type=radio] {
    opacity: 0; 
}

#image-expand input:checked ~ .content {
    width: 275px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background:#000;
    height:80vh;
      margin-left: 380px;;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#image-expand .content, #image-expand label, #image-expand input {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}


#image-expand label:hover ~ input:checked + .content {
    width: 275px;
}


#image-expand label:hover ~ .content {
    width: 111px;
}

#image-expand input{margin-right: 0;}

#image-expand input:checked {
    margin-right: 587px;
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, so it is clear, what you are asking. And your jsfiddle is a mess, could you fix it a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to add JavaScript to a .css file then the answer is you cannot add scripts to a css file, you would have to do it in a javascript file or inside  tags in your html file. You should keep these vastly different components of your website/app separate.
Also, as commented, your fiddle is a mess and your question does not make much sense grammatically. In future add lots of comments etc to the fiddle, and only post what is relevant to the question.